# How to write a single view function to render multiple html from diferent urls path?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views

I am trying to avoid self coping of views functions but have no idea ho to do it.
My views have a minor differences and there is definitely a way to 
render html pages with a single function in this case. I experimented with urls "name" value but failed. I just started with django and hope that experienced programers have a solution. Thank you for your help.

```
urls.py

    urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('', views.index, name='index'),
        path('about/', views.about, name='about'),
        path('team/', views.team, name='team'),
        path('contacts/', views.contacts, name='contacts'),
        path('researches/', views.researches, name='researches'),
        path('publications/', views.publications, name='publications'),
    ]
```

and

```
views.py

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'website/index.html')

def about(request):
    return render(request, 'website/about.html')

def team(request):
    return render(request, 'website/team.html')

def publications(request):
    return render(request, 'website/publications.html')

def researches(request):
    return render(request, 'website/researches.html')

def contacts(request):
    return render(request, 'website/contacts.html')
```

Comment: Are these actually templates (with tags that need parsing), or just static HTML files?

Comment: There are actual templates

Comment: Since you are not passing a context to render, it conveys the impression that though these are templates, they are really just static HTML pages. if that is the case, you can arrange to deliver them as static content. If they are not static, please post your actual code

Comment: There are just static HTML pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to thank all people who tried to help me. 
Your advises inspired me for a solution. I used a code below and it works good.
It appears that there is no need to create a separate view and you may use TemplateView for static html file rendering. That's exactly what I was looking for.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'), name="index"),
    path('about/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='about.html'), name="about"),
    path('team/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='team.html'), name="team"),
    path('contacts/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='contacts.html'), name="contacts"),
    path('researches/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='researches.html'), name="researches"),
    path('publications/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='publications.html'), name="publications"),
]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can capture a slug in the URL and use it to determine which template to render.

```
path('<slug:slug>', views.general_page, ...)
```

...

```
def general_page(request, slug):
    return render(request, 'website/{}.html'.format(slug))
```

Answer (score 0):

If your site is completely static, you may consider using a static framework, like [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/).

This way you don't have to depend on the host server's features, and avoid issues that may arise when you use a complex framework like django.

Answer (score 0):

This work for me i import the views.py in url.py.

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='about'),
    path('team/', views.team, name='team'),
    path('contacts/', views.contacts, name='contacts'),
    path('researches/', views.researches, name='researches'),
    path('publications/', views.publications, name='publications'),
]
```

or

```
from layout.views import index,team,about ...
```

just import your views which folder is located, in this case i import views from the folder(app) **layout**